# Can I run into any issues if I compile native code using different versions of the Android NDK?

Tags: android, compilation, android-ndk

I don't often have to work with native code in my Android projects.

Now I need to compile a few CPP files and include an `*.so` library to my app. The version of the Android NDK on my machine is different than the one on our continuous integration server.

Mine is 16.1.4479499, and the one on the continuous integration server is revision 12b (June 2016).

I compiled my project on both machines, extracted `*.so` libs, and they were binary equal as Beyond Compare showed.

I remember some colleagues from my previous job running into some issues when they used different versions of the Android NDK to compile the same source code. But it happened a few years ago, so I'm sure it might be the case in 2018.

Comment: Sure. It may not be very common, but it can happen. I recently ran into an issue where the definition of `_POSIX_THREAD_SAFE_FUNCTIONS` had changed between different NDK versions, which in and of itself isn't a problem, but the change triggered a bug in boost::filesystem that made directory traversal fail on some Android versions.

Comment: @Michael thank you. You could convert your comment to an answer :)